# How to loop through a users gallery picture stored in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

I have the following table photos where users store a bunch of images based on their user_id.

id: 1 |
user_photos: image1 |
user_id: 3

id: 2 |
user_photos: image2 |
user_id: 3

id: 3 |
user_photos: image3 |
user_id: 3

id: 4 |
user_photos: image4 |
user_id: 2

How do I fetch out user_id 3 data and display it in an image tag to display 3 pictures of that user.

Back-end database code

```
let select_photos_sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = ?";
 mysql_connection.query(select_photos_sql, [session_id], function (error, 
rows) {
if(error){
    res.send("An error has occurred, please try again later.");
} else {

    if(rows.length > 0){ 

        var photos_arr = [];
        var photo_count = 0;
        rows.forEach(function (row) {

            let photos = row.user_photos;

            console.log(photos);
            photos_arr.push(photos);
            photo_count = photo_count+1;
        });
        if (photo_count == rows.length) {
            res.render("user_photos", {photos: photos_arr});
        }

    } else {
        res.send("No photos found.");
    }
}
});
```

The code above puts the users data into an array... [image, image, image]. This isn't useful because when I try to put it in an image tag, following will result into this... the image src = "image, image, image". How do I display it individually. I was expecting 3 image tags.

user_photos.ejs

```
<% for(let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++){ %>
        <img src="<%= photos %>" alt="">
    <% } %>
```

Since this specific user has 3 different images, I want to see 3 different image tags corresponding to this user. I appreciate everyone's help. Thank you!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 1):

In the src attribute, you pass the entire array.
Below you can find an example of how it should be it using a `for of` loop instead of the classic one.

```
<% for(let photo of photos){ %>
     <img src="<%= photo %>" alt="">
 <% } %>
```